# Shotwell 0.32.0 can't drag and drop, can't import from laptop folders

Tags: shotwell

I am a newbie to Linux - about two years, but no coder. I have had all the usual problems getting photos from an Iphone to Linux, so finally put everything on Google photos and then downloaded them to my laptop.

I'm not even sure how to find the latest version/kernal/distro I'm on! I think this is the info needed:
5.15.0-91-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 14 13:30:08 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Linux Mint 21.1 Vera

This morning I removed Shotwell 0.30.0 and installed 0.32.0 since I understood that would handle HEIC files. And for the few photos I have moved over individually, it does. But I still can't just import photos into Shotwell. I try dragging and dropping them, and it acts like its doing it, says there were dupes that weren't brought over, etc. but then the photos don't appear anywhere in Shotwell. And when I try to import from file, the files are all greyed out. If I hit "enter" on a folder (the folders aren't greyed out), it gives me a similar response to dragging and dropping - as if its doing something, but then nothing appears anywhere.
Can anyone help?